# How to create a select from list in java?

Tags: java

I am working on an enter options list, but I cannot find a way to make some of my rsults be entered through a drop-down list, rather than my typing in. What can I do?

```
strSystolicBloodPressure =etSystolicBloodPressure.getText().toString();
strDiastolicBloodPressuretDiastolicBloodPressure.getText().toString();
strTemperatureCelcius = etTemperatureCelsius.getText().toString();
strSmokingType = etSmokingType.getText().toString();
strSmokingAmount = etSmokingAmount.getText().toString();
strCurrentSmoker = etCurrentSmoker.getText().toString();
strTimeSmoking = etTimeSmoking.getText().toString();
strGenetics = etGenetics.getText().toString();
strRace = etRace.getText().toString();
strSymptoms = etSymptoms.getText().toString();

int age = Integer.valueOf(strAge);
int sex = Integer.valueOf(strSex);
int bmi = Integer.valueOf(strBMI);
int systolic_blood_pressure = Integer.valueOf(strSystolicBloodPressure);
int diastolic_blood_pressure = Integer.valueOf(strDiastolicBloodPressure);
int temperature_celsius = Integer.valueOf(strTemperature);
int smoking_type = Integer.valueOf(strSmokingType);
int smoking_amount = Integer.valueOf(strSmokingAmount);
int current_smoker = Integer.valueOf(strCurrentSmoker);
int time_smoking = Integer.valueOf(strTimeSmoking);
int genetics = Integer.valueOf(strGenetics);
int race = Integer.valueOf(strRace);
int symptoms = Integer.valueOf(strSymptoms);
```

Comment: Without knowledge of the UI framework you're using (web-based? With AJAX? Spring MVC? Swing? Java FX?), it's impossible to answer your question. The code you've provided provides no context, nor any obvious association with your question.

Comment: It is web-based. I am working on a risk assessment that will allow for users to input their criteria. I would like to make it so that they are able to pick options from a drop menu, rather than enter it into a textbox.

Answer (score 2):

The answer very much depends on which web framework you're using. If you're using Wicket, you could create a [DropDownChoice](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET/dropdownchoice-examples.html). If you're using Spring MVC, you would populate an `List` with the choices in your model and create a `<select>` in the corresponding JSP.

If you provide more information on which technology stack you're using, we can provide you with more specific guidance.

Comment: If it's any help, I'm applying this program into the Google App Engine.